# Change default type of int in Pascal with fpc and VS Code

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm using Free Pascal Compiler (fpc) with VS Code. While playing around I discovered, that the standard type for `integer` is `smallint`, when declaring a variable like this:

```
var i: integer;
```

When I use `longint`
the highest value is 2147483647.

Is there a way to change the standard to `'longint'`, when using `'integer'` in the declaration?

For clarification please see the following program:

```
program Test(output);

var
    i: longint;
    j: smallint;
    k: integer;

begin
    i := 234234234;
    j := 234234234;
    k := 234234234;
    writeln(i);
    writeln(j);
    writeln(k)
end.
```

The output on my machine is:

234234234

8570

8570

so integer and smallint have the same range which is unusual if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You can read this document: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/current/ref/refsu4.html#x26-250003.1.1

Comment: Thank you, I will use int64 if I run into some range problems. It's weird tho.

Answer (score 1):

The default FPC dialect is a Turbo Pascal compatible dialect.

Switch to a delphi mode with a -Sd parameter or  {$Mode delphi} in the source.

You can add the -Sd parameter to the fpc.cfg if you don't want to enter each time.